# Bevel modifier only works with LIMIT set to NONE

Tags: modeling, bevel

As you can see the bevel function works when free to operate without any LIMIT set.
Object scale is 1, I can't see any issue anywhere.

[image]

Here it's with LIMIT set to ANGLE. Angle is to 30, many edges are at 45 or 90 degrees, none gets beveled:

[image]

Here I tried with 2 edges with MEAN BEVEL WEIGHT at 1:

[image]

Again no effect:

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be some geometry in your model that results in overlapping geometry after bevel so the bevel is stopped at that point by Clamp Overlap feature:

[image]

Resulting geometry differs with different Limit Method, so it must be the case with angle limit but not with no limit. There is no other explanation.

Comment: I thought of _Clamp Overlap_ too, but if this is enabled it clamps even if you have set the _Limit Method_ to _None_... but maybe I just cannot find a constellation of vertices/edges where this happens.

Comment: Yes it does clamp in both ases. But the resulting geometry itself is different when beveling with limits and without, because different edges get beveled(or not), so it must be that it happens to have overlaps with the particular edges beveled with limits, but not when all edges are beveled. I don't think it's very likely to be any other mysterious cause. We'll see when/if the file is shared for sure.

Comment: Yeah I found it is easy to do something the other way round: clamping when set to no limit, but not clamping with an angle limit. My problem is I cannot figure out what geometry issue might be the trigger here, so I do not know what answer I could offer to solve it (sure, disabling clamping might help with the symptoms but not the cause).

Comment: Well... Bevel works fine on tidy geometry. Maybe checking for overlapping geometry, concave n-gons, non-manifold geometry and things like that is a good idea. I mean... This is what we all are going to do first if the file is shared... :D

Comment: Thank you very much, effectively CLAMP OVERLAP solved the problem. Now my question is: do I have some bad overlapping geometry somewhere? If I try a MERGE VERTEX by distance, I get 0 vertexes removed. The model seems healthy. Is it possible that I have overlapping polygons using the same vertexes?

Comment: @PolyMad That's the question. Pretty sure you have something messed up there, but if you already tried to look for it and did not find it, we might need you to upload your model to see for ourselves. Because as I mention above, disabling clamping only removes the symptoms, not the cause for the problem. Martynas: Of course that's what we are going to look for - this was my point, we need the file to really help solving the issue instead of just making it look okay... basically I think this answer is a workaround - but it got accepted, so I would not bother anymore to find the real problem ;)

Comment: To be clear, I did not intend to present this as a solution, just an explanation. I definitely agree to Gordon Brinkmann it only being a symptom of a problem. You should fix whatever is wrong with the geometry. Unless you are not going to work on it any more and you are sure the issues this causes are not a problem(maybe not visible).

Comment: Found the problem. I have 4 booleans active on the object. I added a vertex weld modifier right after all of them, before the bevel modifier, and that fixed the problem. Clearly one or more boolean were producing very close vertexes that limited the amount of beveling possible. Thank you everyone for the help!